# vim under cygwin: can't pipe vim buffer to external program

Tags: vim, cygwin

I have cygwin installed on a Windows 7 box. In that environment, I use vim heavily for code development. I have several small filter-like programs that I use during that process, piping vim buffer content to them and capturing their output in the usual vim way. I wrote these while using vim on UNIX systems, and they work fine there. When I try to use them under cygwin, they almost always fail, giving the following sort of error:

```
      1 [main] gvim 25276 exception::handle: Exception: STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION
   6630 [main] gvim 25276 open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to gvim.exe.stackdump
      1 [main] gvim 44480 exception::handle: Exception: STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION
    353 [main] gvim 44480 open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to gvim.exe.stackdump
      1 [main] gvim 30724 exception::handle: Exception: STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION
    411 [main] gvim 30724 open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to gvim.exe.stackdump
      1 [main] gvim 468 exception::handle: Exception: STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION
    397 [main] gvim 468 open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to gvim.exe.stackdump
      1 [main] gvim 28116 exception::handle: Exception: STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION
    401 [main] gvim 28116 open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to gvim.exe.stackdump
      1 [main] gvim 35968 exception::handle: Exception: STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION
    345 [main] gvim 35968 open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to gvim.exe.stackdump
    258 [main] vim 39032 fork: child -1 - died waiting for longjmp before initialization, retry 0, exit code 0x600, errno 11

 Cannot fork
```

Can anyone tell me what's going on here, and how to fix it?

Comment: what command/program is that? how did you "pipe" to that command?

Comment: The program is, as I said, of my own devising, and is a pipe -- it reads STDIN and writes STDOUT. It happens to be named j (~/bin/j), and the command I used was, e.g., 5!jj.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try [rebasing](http://cygwin.wikia.com/wiki/Rebaseall) cygwin? Some of the errors related to forking usually go away with this procedure.